# Inverse Laplace Transform using Jordan's Lemma?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, residue-calculus

Following is the question that i am trying to solve:

"Consider a second order linear ODE

$x\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}+x\dfrac{dy}{dx}+(3-2x)y=0$

**A)** Find the solution employing Laplace integrals by assuming $\zeta$ to be a complex variable and look for a solution of the form

$y=\int_C e^{x\zeta}d\zeta$ ; where $C$ is a contour in the $\zeta$-plane to be determined, but that starts at $\zeta=\alpha$ and ends at $\zeta=\beta$. Differentiate the above expression and plug it into the ODE to get the following expression after integration by parts:

$e^{x\zeta}(\zeta^{2} + \zeta - 2)v |_{\alpha}^{\beta} + \int_C \left[2(\zeta-1)v + \dfrac{dv}{d\zeta}(\zeta-1)(\zeta+2)\right]e^{x\zeta} d\zeta = 0$

**B)** Set the terms in square brackets in the integral equal to zero and obtain an equation for $v(\zeta)$ and solve it to get an explicit equation. Assuming that one can choose the endpoints of the contour $C$ such that

$e^{x\zeta}(\zeta^{2} + \zeta - 2)v |_{\alpha}^{\beta} = 0$ ; obtain a final form of the variable y as the solution of ODE as

$y = \int_C \dfrac{e^{x\zeta}}{{(\zeta+2})^{2}} d\zeta$

**C)** The final step is to exactly identify $C$ in the $\zeta$-plane. Here is a hint. The requirements are that the contour $C$ have end points that cause the terms identified above to vanish. Also you want to choose a contour such that you can evaluate the integral in the above expression using the residue theorem. HINT: Enclose the pole at $\zeta = -2$ and let your contours start and end in the negative real axis. The relevant contour should look like a keyhole. Use the residue theorem to evaluate the integral and obtain a solution of the form

$y = (2\pi K)ixe^{-2x}$ ; where $K$ is an arbitrary constant.

**My solution** I solved this problem till part B and i think that i can get part C, but can someone help in doing part C thoroughly? Do i create the contour as hinted in the question or do i create an annulus with $\zeta = -2$ as the center?

Comment: Can you do it using regular Laplace Transforms (Table) and then using the complex approach and compare?

Comment: I can. But i am not sure about the shape of the contour